# Ubuntu 20.04 gets stuck when normal using it

Tags: 20.04, gnome, kernel, hard-drive, hardware

my Ubuntu 20.04 installation which runs on my desktop machine gets daily stuck while doing normal browsing and operations. Only the alt+stamp+reisub combo gets it back. Gnome gets totally frozen, and ssh won't respond anymore after entering my user's password. I firstly thought it might have been the 10 years old hard disk, so I replaced it with a new one and performed a clean install, but the issue is still there.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, when I access to an old harddrive, it often needs to spin up and File Manager goes black for a few seconds. Some websites full of adverts slowing Firefox down and blackout for several seconds, my computer is old but it has 12 core 24 threads and 64 GB Ram, I suspect those websites have nasty scripts. Stamp > Super/Meta Reisub > SysRq in English expression